# AWS codedeploy blue green deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have setup code pipeline for end to end automatic  deployment of revision on EC2 instances using cloudformation template, the deployment group is of type blue/green for codedploy.

But I dont understand how to keep the code deployment group in sync with newly created auto scaling group (green).

Do I have to create new lambda invoke action in pipeline after successful deployment to update the newly created auto scaling group name.

Comment: I am not managing code deploy via CF but managing the individual pieces like EC2 instances, LB, ASG etc using cloud formation. But does CF has the capability to manage code deployment group in Blue/Green style. Please share some docs which I can refer.

Comment: Yes, CFN can manage and provision all resources for blue/geen ECS deployment for you as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html).

Comment: ECS I know but how to do the same with EC2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CloudFormation **does not support** Blue/Green deployments for EC2 [platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codedeploy-deploymentgroup.html#cfn-codedeploy-deploymentgroup-deploymentstyle):

> For blue/green deployments, AWS CloudFormation supports deployments **on Lambda compute platforms only**.

Support for [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html) is very new.

To create deployment group for blue/green for EC2 platform you would have to create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation .

The custom resource would be based on a lambda function, and in that lambda function you would use [create_deployment_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codedeploy.html#CodeDeploy.Client.create_deployment_group) to define blue/green details for your EC2 instances. As part of this process, you will have an option to choose how to deal with **AutoScaling group**, e.g.

```
        "greenFleetProvisioningOption": {
             "action": "COPY_AUTO_SCALING_GROUP"
        }
```

For creation of custom resource, [crhelper](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/aws-cloudformation-custom-resource-creation-with-python-aws-lambda-and-crhelper/) by AWS is very useful.

Hope this helps and hope Blue/Green for EC2 will be supported by CloudFormation soon.

Comment: Thanks this means to support end to end automation for blue green deployment style of EC2 either I have to manually update after every deployment or some form of lambda function that will update all the components correctly after codedeploy completes successfully.

Comment: @prassank You can have second custom resource to deal with specific deployments through CloudFormation. The endgame is that for now its painful to perform b/g on EC2 through CloudFormation.

Comment: Interesting, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments.html blue/green on an EC2 is an option.

Comment: @yurez From the link you posted: "Currently, only ECS blue/green deployments are supported. " in CloudFormatino, not EC2.

Comment: Did this recently change? From the link: "If you use an EC2/On-Premises compute platform, be aware that blue/green deployments work with Amazon EC2 instances only."